# Niblack algorithm implementation Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have implemented Niblack's algorithm in Matlab. However, I am achieving some questionable results.

I downloaded some test images that I tried to perform some document binarization on. However, I'm not sure they are looking correct. Below are the images and my code, I've tried to make it modular by doing various functions. Thanks!

[image: start image]

[image: Result]

upped k level to 2
result: 
[image]

my code

```
% K value
k_threshold = -0.1;

%input image
image1 = imread('test1.jpg');

%convert to grayscale
image1 = rgb2gray(image1);

%convert to double
image1 = double(image1);

% normalise to [0,1] range
image1 = image1 / max(image1(:));

%mean filtering
mean = averagefilter2(image1);

%standard deviation
standardDeviation = standardDev(image1, mean);

%calculate binary image
binaryImage = image1 >=  (mean + k_threshold * standardDeviation);


%display image
display = displayImage(binaryImage, image1);

function deviation = standardDev(image1, mean)
    meanSquare = averagefilter2(image1.^2);
    deviation = (meanSquare - mean.^2).^0.5;

end
function [X,Y] = displayImage (binaryImage, image1)
close;

figure;
X = imshow(image1); title('original image');

figure;
 Y = imshow(binaryImage); title('binary image');

end

function img=averagefilter2(image1)
    meanFilter = fspecial('average',[3 3]);
    img = imfilter (image1,meanFilter);
end
```

Comment: The value for k_threshold seems very small, how does it look with larger values?

Comment: I upped it to 2 and just edited my post ^^

Comment: How about leaving k_threshold where it was at -0.1, and increasing the size of the filter, e.g. 50*50 instead of 3*3?

Comment: tried 30 30 works well now thank you